# How do I add the http protocol to a link?

Tags: php, http, yii

This should be basic knowledge, but somehow it eludes me. It has been working fine up till now, but for some reason my code no longer adds the http protocol...

I have `$model->www` which contains `www.some-page.no` (plain text).

Up till now I've been outputting this as follows:

```
<a href="<?= $model->www; ?>> Click me </a>
```

Expected output should be `http://www.some-page.no`
but now I get `http://my-local-machine.com/page/a/http://www.some-page.no`

If I do `<a href="http://<?= $model->www; ?>> Click me </a>` it works fine. The problem is that I don't know if the URL already contains `http://`.

Is there a Yii way or a PHP way of adding http protocol if the link does not have it? Or do I have to custom make a function that checks for the string `http://`?

The link is properly sanitized. So there is no need for `htmlspecialchars` or similar functions.

Comment: Assuming this is Yii 1, you can most likely use [`createAbsoluteUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createAbsoluteUrl-detail)

Comment: Didn't work. `Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl($model->www)` gave me `http://localhost.no/www.some-page.no`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$url = 'www.google.be';
if (parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) === null) $url = 'http://'.$url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
<a href="http://<?php str_replace('http://', '', $model->www); ?>" Click me</a>
```

UPDATE: If you are also concerned about other protocols (see DarkBee's comment):

```
<a href="http://<?php str_replace(array('http://', 'https://', 'ftp://'), '', $model->www); ?>" Click me</a>
```

Comment: And what about `https`

Comment: What about https?  The question only asks about http.